# How to implement UI based on nested array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, logic

I have an array with some dynamic value which will have array of array and according to inner array length need to show **OR** text.

**Example:**

**JSON data:**

```
const renderArr = [
  {
    label: "Abc",
    value: []
  },
  {
    label: "XyZ",
    value: ["Test", "Exam"]
  },
  {
    label: "Dex",
    value: []
  },
  {
    label: "Mno",
    value: ["Momo", "Pizza"]
  },
  {
    label: "Pqr",
    value: []
  }
];
```

According to above structure there are value in  **renderArr[[1](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-firefly-265vs?file=/src/App.js:432-437)].value and renderArr[[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsL0j.png)].value**. So i need to show "OR" text between these in UI

**Expected Logic:**

```
I want to show OR condition based on below condition

let currentValue = renderArr[index].value.length > 0 then

If nextValue = renderArr[index+1].value.length > 0 then show OR condition, NOTE: it'll check till it not found the value.length > 0 for every index
```

Below is my logic, which is not working properly.

**My Logic:**

```
shouldShowNextOr = (value, rootIndex) => {
    let shouldShow = false;
    let f = renderArr;
    if (rootIndex < 4) {
      switch (rootIndex) {
        case 0:
          shouldShow =
            f[1].value.length > 0 ||
            f[2].value.length > 0 ||
            f[3].value.length > 0 ||
            f[4].value.length > 0
              ? true
              : false;
          break;
        case 1:
          shouldShow =
            f[2].value.length > 0 ||
            f[3].value.length > 0 ||
            f[4].value.length > 0
              ? true
              : false;
          break;
        case 2:
          shouldShow =
            f[3].value.length > 0 || f[4].value.length > 0 ? true : false;
          break;
        case 3:
          shouldShow = f[4].value.length > 0 ? true : false;
          break;
        default:
          shouldShow = false;
      }
    }

    return shouldShow;
  };
```

Here is [online codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-firefly-265vs?file=/src/App.js:432-437)

**Current Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the `renderArray` (`data` in my example), and remove all items with empty `value` array. Render the filtered array, and if an item is not the last (`i < filteredData.length - 1`) you can render "OR" after it:

```js
const { useMemo } = React;

const App = ({ data }) => {
  const filteredData = useMemo(() => data.filter(o => o.value.length), [data]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
    {filteredData.map((o, i) => (
      <React.Fragment key={o.label}>
        <div>
          <span>{o.label}</span> ={" "}
          {o.value.join(" and ")}
        </div>
        {i < filteredData.length - 1 &&
          <span>OR<br /></span>
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}
    </div>
  );
};
 
 const renderArr = [{"label":"Abc","value":[]},{"label":"XyZ","value":["Test","Exam"]},{"label":"Dex","value":[]},{"label":"Mno","value":["Momo","Pizza"]},{"label":"Pqr","value":[]}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={renderArr} />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

If you need the original index, use `Array.map()` to include it in the object before filtering:

```js
const { useMemo } = React;

const App = ({ data }) => {
  const filteredData = useMemo(() => 
    data
      .map((o, index) => ({ ...o, index }))
      .filter(o => o.value.length)
  , [data]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
    {filteredData.map((o, i) => (
      <React.Fragment key={o.label}>
        <div>
          <span>{o.label} - {o.index}</span> ={" "}
          {o.value.join(" and ")}
        </div>
        {i < filteredData.length - 1 &&
          <span>OR<br /></span>
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}
    </div>
  );
};
 
 const renderArr = [{"label":"Abc","value":[]},{"label":"XyZ","value":["Test","Exam"]},{"label":"Dex","value":[]},{"label":"Mno","value":["Momo","Pizza"]},{"label":"Pqr","value":[]}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={renderArr} />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Is possible without remove all items with empty value? because I am using the index value for different use

Comment: I've added a solution that includes the original index.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be : Store all the index values of the `renderArray` which has `value` in another array(`arr` in my example). Check if `rootIndex` is part of `arr`.

Here's the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-kowalevski-o2365?file=/src/App.js)

```
arrIndex = [];

shouldShowNextOr = (value, rootIndex) => {
let shouldShow = false;
let f = renderArr;
let arr = this.arrIndex;
//storing all the indices which has value
if (arr.length === 0) {
  f.forEach(function (a, index) {
    if (a.value.length > 0) arr.push(index);
  });
}
//check if root index exists
if (arr.includes(rootIndex) && arr.length > 1) {
  //skip the last element in the array.
  if (rootIndex === arr[arr.length - 1]) {
    shouldShow = false;
  } else {
    shouldShow = true;
  }
}

return shouldShow;
```

};

Input:

```
const renderArr = [
  {
    label: "Abc",
    value: []
  },
  {
    label: "XyZ",
    value: ["Yes", "No"]
  },
  {
    label: "Dex",
    value: []
  },
  {
    label: "Mno",
    value: ["Hi","Hello"]
  },
  {
    label: "Pqr",
    value: ["Yes", "No"]
  }
];

Output:



XyZ = Yes and No
OR
Mno = Hi and Hello
OR
Pqr = Yes and No
```